# How to change color for Handlebars title and property value?

Tags: html, css, node.js, handlebars.js

I have the following list:

```
<li>Equipment Area:{{equipment_area}}</li>
<li>Equipment Type: {{equipment_type}}</li>
<li>Manufacturer: {{manufacturer}}</li>
<li>Model Number: {{model_number}}</li>
<li>Serial Number: {{serial_number}}</li>
<li>Service: {{service}}</li>
<li>Capacity: {{capacity}}</li>
<li>Comments: {{general_comments}}</li>
<li>Total Cost: {{total_of_new_installation}}</li>
```

Once trying to change the font color of the titles to blue, I added some inline style:

```
<li style="blue">Equipment Area:{{equipment_area}}</li>
```

However, when I put in an inline style as seen above, the entire list item (the title and the associated value) changes to blue.

I would like the title to be blue and the template value to be white. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
<li style="blue">Equipment Area:<p style="color: white;">{{equipment_area}}</p></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap each part in a `span` and give it a class, like this:

```
<li>
   <span class="list-title">Equipment Area:</span>
   <span class="list-value">{{equipment_area}}</span>
</li>
```

Then you can style each class as you want...

Answer (score 0):

Using inline style you can just use the `color` property to specify the color of text inside of an [HTML span tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp).

```html
<li><span style="color: blue">Equipment Area:</span><span style="color: white">{{equipment_area}}</span></li>
<li><span style="color: blue">Equipment Type:</span><span style="color: white">{{equipment_type}}</span></li>
<li><span style="color: blue">Manufacturer:</span><span style="color: white">{{manufacturer}}</span></li>
<li><span style="color: blue">Model Number:</span><span style="color: white">{{model_number}}</span></li>
```

To avoid repetition (going to each line item adding the inline style), better is to add title and property classes to the spans and style in CSS, like this

```css
.title {
  color: blue;
  }

.value {
  color: white;
  }
  
.title:hover {
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<li>
  <span class="title">Equipment Area:</span>
  <span class="value">{{equipment_area}}</span>
</li>

<li>
  <span class="title">Equipment Type:</span>
  <span class="value">{{equipment_type}}</span>
</li>

<li>
  <span class="title">Manufacturer:</span>
  <span class="value">{{manufacturer}}</span>
</li>

<li>
  <span class="title">Model Number:</span>
  <span class="value">{{model_number}}</span>
</li>
```

(the snippet was updated to change the titles color to red when you mouse over them)

Comment: Am I doing the CSS right.....because it is not changing....@Tiago Martins Peres

Comment: li .list-title  {
    color: #fff;
  }
  li .list-value{
    color: #64a5b7;
  }
  li .list-title:hover li {
    color: #64a5b7;
  }

Comment: If you have classes list-title and list-value and want to use the CSS :hover selector, then this is the CSS, `.list-title { color: #fff; } .list-value { color: #64a5b7; } .list-title:hover { color: #64a5b7; }`

Comment: Good flowover. Don't forget to upvote and accept as answer.

Comment: ^^^^^^^ @flowover